# DNN (DotNetNuke) DDR Menu in IE 8 - security warning

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dotnetnuke

We are using DNN 6.02.07 and the DDR menu provider. When users navigate using this menu in IE 8 in an https site, they receive a security warning regarding mixed content between http and https content. I have searched my site extensively for any mixed content and it really comes down to the ddr menu itself. When I remove the menu, the warning go way. Does anyone have any ideas here? We would like to upgrade to DNN 7, but we can't at the moment.

Comment: Do you have any graphics in the DDR menu? Or possibly anything else referenced by a full URL to someplace?

Comment: I've looked everywhere for a full URL, don't see one anywhere.

Comment: What about the DNN tags?

Comment: This is in the Taxonomy settings, correct? Don't see much of anything there, just some plain text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what ended up fixing it for me:

Within the DNNMenu.min.js, there was a reference to a spacer gif for ie 8 users only.

Here is the code:
url("+c.dnnNavParams.PathSystemImage+"spacer.gif)"

Here is the fix:
"url('https://www.mysite.org/images/spacer.gif')"

After hard coding this spacer gif as secure, we have not seen the problem since!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in DNN with mixed mode content error. 
The problem came from a custom URL rewrite module we have that was not returning https correctly for an iFrame on the page. So the page was https, but when DNN was rewriting the URL for the iFrame with our custom url rewrite module, there was a logic error in our code and the iFrame was coming as http. This also happened when we upgraded DNN to v6, so not sure if something in the core had changed that threw our logic off?

Anyway, check your URL rewrite module is behaving when rendering the URLs in the menu.

Also check for any iFrames or code script blocks (jquery, jqueryui, etc) that are not getting their content from a secure (https) source. Maybe even images?

Comment: Thanks for the info, for our issue, the security warning is quite intermittent, making it very difficult to track down. It seems to be related to how quickly a webresource.axd can load. This web resource contains some of the telerik images that come with DNN...still trying things to try and resolve this